# Override get_config (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am upgrading my Codeigniter from 2.2.1 to 3.0.0. A lot of things has been changed espacially sessions.

CI 2.2.1 and before had this function as follow in system/core/Common.php: Line around 214.

```
   function &get_config($replace = array())
     {
        static $_config;

        if (isset($_config))
    {
        return $_config[0];
    }
```

This is the function that extends system/core/Input.php

application/core/MY_Input.php

```
    Class MY_Input extends CI_Input
    {

     function _clean_input_keys($str, $fatal = true)
     {

    $config = &get_config('config');

    if ( ! preg_match("/^[".$config['permitted_uri_chars']."]+$/i", 
       rawurlencode($str)))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
    }

    // Clean UTF-8 if supported
    if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
    {
        $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
    }


    return $str;
    }

    }
```

Until here everything worked fine. After upgrading to CI# system/core/Common.php has changed the function to: Line around 238

```
    function &get_config(Array $replace = array())
      {
      static $config;

      if (empty($config))
      {
```

How could I match the param for this function in MY_Input.php

```
  $config = &get_config('config');
```

Comment: you are providing the string while you mentioned in the function that the argument should be an array. that's why it giving you the error.

Comment: @john It worked fine for CI 2.2.1. Why not for CI 3?

Comment: I don't know about CI but I know that if you specify the argument type in the function definition then the argument type should be the same in the function call.

Comment: $config is an array. It pulls out config.php.  Doing var_dump($config) confirms that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word 'Array' before $replace in the v3 code enforces the type of the argument, that is the reason you are getting the error.

'config' was not a valid value for that argument. Remove it and you should be good to go.

```
    $config = &get_config('config');
```

to

```
   $config = &get_config('');
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$config=array('db'=>'some value','someother'=>'value');
 $config = &get_config($config);  **//  LINE 6**
```